# Is there a way to bulk move objects under a collection

Tags: selection-tools

I have created a forest of about 300 trees and I would like to have all of them moved under a collection called tree. I can select them using pattern matching, however when I go to drag and drop the selected item into the new collection it only moves the one I clicked on in the object tree. Is there a way to bulk move all of the selected items to said collection?

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce this in 2.83 .. I can select multiple, either in the 3D View, or the Outliner, and left-drag them into the collection by releasing the left mouse-button over the appropriate line.

It may be easier, with such a large selection, in Object Mode, in the 3D View or the Outliner, to hit <kbd>M</kbd>. You should then be offered a dropdown menu of collections to which you may move the selection, or the option to create a new collection to move it to.

Comment: Yea using selection with pattern matching then using M allowed me to move all to the desired collection. Still feels a bit counterintuitive that if I select all these individual objects I am not allowed to drag and drop them in the collections.

Comment: The drag-and-drop not working is a bit of a mystery.. it works for me...  I'll try it with a very large selection and see of it makes any difference.

Comment: I can't reproduce either, except if the object has a parent and the parent is in the collection where you want to drop the object, which is weird, perhaps it is considering that the child object is already in the collection, as its parent is, but it is actually not, if you see into the parent hierarchy, the child is greyed. Also, when you drag and drop a parent object into a collection, its child remains in the original collection, which seems to be the same issue, All this seems counter-intuitive to me. Isn't it a thing that should be corrected?

Comment: It might be becasue the objects did not have a parrent other than the original scene collection?

Answer (score 0):

In the object outliner, you can select an item with left click then you can hit <kbd>Shift</kbd> and left click on another object in the outliner. This will select every object and collection between your two choices, from there just drag and drop them where you want them.